# It doesn't belong here doesn't allows me to select a suggestion that is not listed

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, flagging

I noticed that lately every time I want to click it doesn't belongs here as a flag I can't find the appropriate community I would suggest. So I find myself writing on other what I think it belongs.

Is this an okay workaround? Please up vote for agreement or down vote for disagreement on this question.

If you can comment a better way to deal with this, please tell me. Also, isn't there a way to add the new communities to the list that are more related to the 'doesn't belong here'? CrossValidated has Data Mining, and Computer Science  seems like things software engineers might want to ask instead only about tools. The last flags I marked (which I hope are right) were for those cases. (Feature request) Can't we have a open field where we can just give the link on the flag such as we have for the category other?

Comment: you might be interested in this MSO discussion: [More options when flagging for migration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

Comment: Thanks gnat! Will look into it~

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The feature already exists, but only for diamond moderators.

Every time a similar feature has been asked for regular users, it has been declined summarily, although I'm certain that everyone who votes to migrate means well, incorrect migrations are quite often. Programmers especially [has suffered a lot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl) from incorrect migrations from Stack Overflow, the past 90 days we have rejected more than 1/3 of questions coming here from Stack Overflow.

The main problem is that although you are required to have at least 3,000 reputation at the source to vote to migrate, you aren't even required to have an account at the target site, and people seem eager to vote to migrate without thinking if the question is actually suitable for the target site.

So I'd say that flagging for moderation attention is not only an acceptable workaround, but imho it's actually the preferred action. We can notify the other site's moderators and only migrate the question if they verify that it is suitable for their site.

In theory, we could discuss adding another migration target. Right now our most popular migration target is Stack Overflow with 170 questions the past 90 days, and our second most popular is Code Review with 9 questions over the same period, too few to justify a migration path. If we start getting a lot of Code Review questions, trust me I'll be the first to nag about it ;)

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful. But I guess Im lacking on something here: If on flag I say it belongs to workflow then I am saying in a way that I vote to move it? I thought flag and moving votes were distinct. Have I been voting without knowing? D:

Comment: @OeufcoquePenteano When you flag for moderation attention, you are asking the moderators to do something that you yourself cannot do either because you don't have the reputation or because it's a moderator only action (anything, not just moving a question). The difference is that when you vote to close the moderators aren't involved.

Comment: oh! got it! i will use the work around then! Thanks!!

Comment: @OeufcoquePenteano Just a note: Computer Science is still _very_ new, it will take some time for the community to define the site, and we have some overlap in expertise. Generally speaking if a question got good answers here, it wouldn't make much sense to move it there (if it's on topic for us, obviously). Read [this recent discussion](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/should-algorithm-and-data-structure-concepts-still-be-on-topic-for-programmers-n) for more details.